# T SQL - Conconate Column Multiple Times

Tags: t-sql, pivot

So I have the following table:

`ID  |   Product_Image` 
`300         |   /300-01.jpg` 
`300          |   /300-02.jpg` 
`301        |   /301.jpg` 
`302          |   /302.jpg`

There could be an unlimited number of images per ID.  I need to concatenate all the image references into one column, and I am having trouble generating the following output:

`ID | Product Images` 
`300 | /300-01.jpg; /300-02.jpg;` 
`301 | /301.jpg;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- cte with test data
;with T (ID, Product_Image) as
(
select 300, '/300-01.jpg' union all
select 300, '/300-02.jpg' union all
select 301, '/301.jpg' union all
select 302, '/302.jpg'
)

select
  T.ID,
  (select T2.Product_Image+'; '
   from T as T2 
   where T.ID = T2.ID
   for xml path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Product_Images
from T
group by T.ID
```

Result:

```
ID   Product_Images
---- -------------------------
300  /300-01.jpg; /300-02.jpg; 
301  /301.jpg; 
302  /302.jpg;
```

Comment: Does this cast before or after concatenation? If after, string may already be truncated to 8k/4k

Comment: @gbn – It does not truncate. My understanding of this is that the result of nested select is a XML datatype with only one value, without any tags, not even a root tag. Rather invalid XML really. `.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'` fetches the only value in the XML as `nvarchar(max)`. You could add a `root('r')` to get a valid xml and use `.value('r[1]', nvarchar(max)` to get the single value of `<r>...</r>`.

Comment: I get it. The XML PATH gives XML, not varchar, so no truncation happens. Ta. I'd have used CROSS APPLY and CAST: will see if I can note any differences in performance.