# collapse strings with same id into comma separated list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Based on some googling I came up with this:

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(max)
)

insert into #temp (id,name) values (1,'bla1')
insert into #temp (id,name) values (1,'bla2')
insert into #temp (id,name) values (3,'bla3')

;with cte1 as
(
    select id, stuff((select ', ' + CAST(t2.name as nvarchar(max))
         from #temp t2 where t1.id = t2.id
         for xml path('')),1,1,'') name
    from #temp t1
)
select id, name from cte1 group by id, name
```

Is this the best way to do things? Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is slightly better as it just sorts on `id` rather than `id,name`

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM #temp
)
SELECT id, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(t2.name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM #temp t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') name
FROM cte t1
```

If you have a table containing just the distinct `id` fields already you would probably be better off using that.

The approach you are using only works correctly if the data is guaranteed not to contain any characters such as `<`, `>`, `&`

Comment: If you fetch the value from the XML like in this answer you don't have to worry about the special XML characters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857975/t-sql-conconate-column-multiple-times/5858219#5858219

Comment: @Mikael - But you do have to worry about other characters such as `CHAR(11)`

Comment: I saw your comment on another question so I have made some tests. The ranges that work is 32-55296 and 57343-65533. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800..U.2BDFFF